# Details View is displaying “System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I dont know how to solve the proble, something is wrong, please help!

the problem is:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Student_0C394DD28745C7061A0EB9964A9FAD1A77E5EB1B24F61D61E2229472BCC850EE', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel'.

```
StudentController:

public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Student student = _db.Students.Include(m => m.Comments).SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            var model = new DetailsViewModel
            {
                Comment = new Comment(),
                Student = student,
                Comments = student.Comments.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ToList()
            };

            return View(student);
        }
```

View:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Student</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.FirstMidName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.FirstMidName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.EnrollmentDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Student.EnrollmentDate)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Student.Enrollments)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Course Title</th>
                    <th>Grade</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                     }
             </table> 
        </dd>
    </dl>


        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Movie</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Comment.Id" name="commentId" />

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Name)
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Email)
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment.Text)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment.Text)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div id="comments">
        @foreach (var c in Model.Comments)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Comment", c)
        }
    </div>

</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Student.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

DetailsViewModel:

```
public Student Student { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

Comment model:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
```

Student Model:

```
public int ID { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(" ", FirstMidName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
```

if somebody didnt understand Im trying add commentaries list at Details page with partial view.

Comment: The error message says exactly what the problem is. Look at it again (ignoring the hex string), and then look at the last line in your `Details` action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a Student Object to the View where you defined waht object it will handle Namely: `@model ContosoUniversity.ViewModels.DetailsViewModel`

You need to either in your controller pass the view a DetailsViewModel or you have to rethink what you are doing/ need to do, and make the view  handle object Student.

i dont know where this model is but something like:

```
@model ContosoUniversity.Models.Student
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DisplayTemplates folder in your Shared Views folder named _Comment.cshtml (i.e. a path like /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/_Comment.cshtml) you should try the following:

1. Rename _Comment.cshtml to Comment.cshtml
2. Replace the following:

   ```
   <div id="comments">
      @foreach (var c in Model.Comments)
      {
          @Html.Partial("_Comment", c)
      }
    </div>
   ```

with the following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Comments)
```

I just fought with this myself and the underscore in the filename was what was breaking things.